# get the text of div using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i want to get the text of div using angularjs . I have this code

```
<div ng-click="update()" id="myform.value">Here </div>
```

where as my controller is something like this

```
    var  myapp= angular.module("myapp",[]);
    myapp.controller("HelloController",function($scope,$http){

    $scope.myform ={};

    function update()
    {
            // If i have a textbox i can get its value from below alert 
            alert($scope.myform.value);
    }
    });
```

Can anyone also recommand me any good link for angularjs . I dont find angularjs reference as a learning source .

Comment: My question would be why do you want the content of the div? To do databinding you can use ng-bind, but since there is no "good" other way to change the content of the div with anything else than binding the value of the div is already on the scope.
For learning check this out [angular codeschool](http://angular.codeschool.com/)

Comment: Most likely you are trying to do something you should not do at all with Angular.

Comment: well i have like and dislike feature .So if user click on div it will change the text to 'unlike' and update the ng-click function too . So in this way everytime user click i have to change the text of the div

Comment: Yes but where is that value comming from should be comming from the angular model, like
`$scope.likeText = 'Like'`
and the function to be
`$scope.update = function() {
$scope.likeText = 'dislike';
}` and in the div you define an attribute ng-bind="likeText"

Comment: yes i am getting values through model and i am getting 1 and 0 from it . so if i am not wrong you are saying me that i use use angularjs variable there as text and just update the value of it right ?

Comment: Thanks @Daniel it works through that way . I was thinking in similar way of doing this as we do in jquery . Please also recommend me any good link to start learning angularjs . I cant able to learn it from reference .

Comment: Hi no problem, i posted a link before to http://campus.codeschool.com/courses/shaping-up-with-angular-js/intro this should be a rather good tutorial on angular.

Answer (score 4):

You should send the click event in the function, your html code should be :

```
<div ng-click="update($event)" id="myform.value">Here </div>
```

And your update function should have the event parameter which you'll get the div element from and then get the text from the element like this :

```
function update(event)
 {
  alert(event.target.innerHTML);
 }
```

Comment: you should really not access the dom elements in in the controller use data binding to glue them together.

Comment: but in his case, if he want to get any DOM element info, he should use the DOM element in the controller to retrieve the text, where else can he do it?!

Comment: well, i have never seen the need to do anything like that, what could not be done by doing it the right data-binding way, if you do not have control over the html rendered there might be a setup where this is required. Normally only inside of a directive you should be touching html directly.

Answer (score 1):

i just thought i put together a proper answer for everybody looking into this question later.

Whenever you do have the desire to change dom elements in angular you need to make a step back and think once more what exactly you want to achieve. Chances are you are doing something wring (unless you are in a link function there you should handle exactly that).

So where is the value comming, it should not come from the dom itself, it should be within your controller and brought into the dom with a ng-bind or {{ }} expression like:

```
<div>{{ likeText }}</div>
```

In the controller now you can change the text as needed by doing:

```
$scope.likeText = 'Like';
$scope.update = function() {
     $scope.likeText = 'dislike'; 
}
```

For angular tutorials there is a good resource here -> http://angular.codeschool.com/

Answer (score 0):

Redefine your function as

```
$scope.update = function() {
 alert($scope.myform.value);
}
```

A better way to do it would be to use ng-model
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel

Check the example, these docs can be a bit wordy

Comment: alert is working but i am not getting the text of the div . I have use the ng-model too

Comment: Does an alert box pop up at all? could you create a fiddle?

Comment: alert does come but its blank

Comment: That means that $scope.myform.value is not defined, it will be if its bound correctly. did you replace the 'id' with ng-model? or bind? can you create a js fiddle or a code pen? else just paste your latest code

Comment: Also, is your div inside an element with ng-controller="HelloController"?

Comment: yes the element is inside the ng-controller . I tried to putt the code on fiddle but its not working as it is on my machine ,but here is the link http://jsfiddle.net/Lxad8tnk/

Comment: Your right the fiddle didnt do much. look at the example here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBind might help