# AngularJS get html element

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using angularjs, and I want to obtain the html element by simply mark an ng-tag.

```
<div ng-xxxx="myDiv"></div>

console.log($scope.myDiv); //<div ng-xxxx="myDiv"></div>
```

Can someone tech me how it can be done?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30883995/getting-the-html-content-of-the-url-specified-in-angularjs

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25564721/get-the-text-of-div-using-angularjs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a plunkr sample that should be close to what you're looking for, or at least a good starting point.

https://plnkr.co/edit/QVd5WJEGq7B9WWyXJBSu?p=preview

So here is an attribute directive, that uses method binding (& binding), which means it accepts an [angular expression](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression) `getHtml: '&'` So here the parent is using the expression to set a scope variable to $content `get-html="$ctrl.string = $content"`. $content is defined by the directive itself in a map, when the expression is executed in the link function. `scope.getHtml({ $content: elem.html() });`

```
.directive('getHtml', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
        getHtml: '&'
    }, 
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
        scope.getHtml({ $content: elem.html() });
    } 
  }; 
});
```

Comment: In fact, I'm looking for a method other than directive.

Comment: Whats wrong with directive? :) This is basically the angular approach, maybe you just need jquery?